# What is meant by "inches of travel"?

Tags: mountain-bike

I am in the market for a mountain bike, and have been reading some mountain bike magazines for info.  They mention particular models as having particular "inches of travel".  What exactly does this mean and what is its importance?

Answer (score 8):

"Inches of travel" refers to how much the shocks can compress before hitting their limit. The more inches of travel the shocks have, the large an impact they can absorb. More travel does not automatically mean that one bike is better than another. Different riding styles and different trail conditions will require different amounts of travel.

Comment: When levers are involved, shock compression and wheel travel migh not match.

Comment: (In which case inches of travel refers to the travel of the wheel)

Comment: *"More travel does not automatically mean that one bike is better than another"*  Yes it does!!!!  So does more gears - and red bikes.  ;-)

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner What's that about [more gears](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/nanodrive/)?